# spectral radius matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $n \times n$ matrix with real eigen values,  $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$  and $\rho(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of the matrix A.

Is the following result true?

$\max\limits_{||x||=1} (Ax,x)=\rho(A)$

It is easy to show the inequality $\max\limits_{||x||=1} (Ax,x) \geq \rho(A)$

Is it possible to prove the other way round

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you only consider $x \in \Bbb R^n$, then the inequality will fail to hold.  Consider for instance
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}.
$$
If we consider complex $x$, however, then the inequality holds. Equality will necessarily hold if $A$ is normal, i.e. if (in the case that $A$ is real) $A^TA = AA^T$.  However,
equality will not hold in general.  Consider for instance
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$
We find that $\rho(A) = 0$, but the numerical radius is $\frac 12$.

Comment: what if in addition, the eigen values are real numbers, then is that result true?

Comment: @Rosy in that case the inequality holds and equality holds if and only if $A$ is normal, which happens if and only if $A = A^T$.